# Why can't a map an ISO transform in a Javascript array map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iso

I have a React file which is using a get call to retrieve JSON data. Within that JSON return is an array featuring objects in the following format:

```
{
    device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e"
    device_type: "MX480"
    domain: "JUNIPER"
    domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6"
    resources: null
    sync_status: "idle"
    sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00"
}
```

What I need to do is map through all of these objects and transform the sync_time using an toISOString().slice(0,10). Here's my feeble effort:

```
const newSyncDates = names.map(item => item.sync_time)
const finalSyncDates = newSyncDates.map((n)=> {
    return n.toISOString().slice(0,10)
})
```

When I run this I am getting an error saying "n.toISOString is not a function". Don't know what to do .... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const finalSyncDates = newSyncDates.map((n)=> {
    return (new Date(n)).toISOString().slice(0,10)
})
```

You tried to access the `toISOString` method on a string instead of a date.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, JSON doesn't have a Date type. You're calling `n.toISOString()` when `n` is still a string.

```
const finalSyncDates = names.map(item => new Date(item.sync_time))
                            .map(n => n.toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

Comment: One last question if you don't mind ... how could i use this to replace the sync_time part of the object while maintaining the rest of the object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just don't use the `.map` method, instead iterate and change the elements of the object as a whole, e.g. `names.forEach(s => s.sync_time = new Date(s.sync_time))`